# Get links from an html page

Tags: linux, terminal, python, shell-script, html

I have a txt file with several html file links. I need to access each link in this txt and grab the links that are inside it and save it to another txt file.

How can I do this for Linux terminal/ shell script / python?

Comment: In case my answer is not applicable, you may want to [edit] your and clarify your post and show an example of how your input file looks like, and what you would like your output to look like.

Answer (score 5):

Install `lynx`, then:

```
lynx -listonly -nonumbers -dump input.html > links.txt
```

Make sure that your input file has a `.html` extension.

For example:

```
$ cat test.html
<a href="http://superuser.com">test</a>
http://google.com
$ lynx -listonly -nonumbers -dump test.html
http://superuser.com/
```

If you instead have a text file that points to HTML files from which you need to get the links, you can iterate over that:

```
while read -r file; do
  lynx -listonly -nonumbers -dump "$file" > "${file%.*}.txt
done < input.txt
```

This will read every line in the text file, use lynx to extract the links, and write them to a .txt file with the same base name as the HTML file they point to.

Answer (score 4):

Cut the question into 2 parts.

#### 1. Take all pages from a text file.

**Assume no logins or credentials are required for the target page.**

Run on a Linux or Unix machine, or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on Windows, in a terminal session

```
wget -i your.txt
```

#### 2. [Extract links from a file](/q/1174066)

And then for each downloaded file, run

```
cat FILE | \
sed 's/href=/\nhref=/g' | \
grep href=\" | \
sed 's/.*href="//g;s/".*//g' >> out.txt
```

In case something is missing, run

```
sudo apt-get install coreutils wget grep sed
```

on a Debian Linux, despite the fact that most systems ship with them by default.

If you choose to do so in a Cygwin session, remember to select `Core Utilities`, `Wget`, `grep` and `sed` when installing.

Comment: Not sure what `http://specify.com` does here… why only this particular link? And what are you writing to the output file, specifically?

Comment: @slhck It's copied from another answer of mine. Forgot that, lol.